# Getting the count of documents within a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a structure of...

```
{ _id = object_id,
  user: name,
  days: { "4/1/2010": {"checked": true},
          "4/2/2011": {"checked": false)}
 }
```

I want to get the total number of days across users.  If `days` was an array, I would do something like...

```
  db.collection.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": null, {"$sum": {"$size": "$days"}}}}])
```

but that won't work since I can't use `size`.  Anyone have suggestions?

Note:  There may be a different number of days missing in the data structure for each user which is why I want to check the count within each user's `days`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) stage to convert `days` pair into arrays followed by [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage in 3.4.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "count":{
      "$sum":{
        "$size":{"$objectToArray":"$days"}
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you but what if I just wanted the number?  I'm using pymongo / python - should I access the value via python?  just want to be sure I'm handling it properly

Comment: i ended up converting it to a list...accessing the only element...then access count from the dictionary

Comment: Are you asking how do you just get count and not _id ? If yes, you can use `$project` stage to suppress the id. Something like `{$project:{_id:0}}`. You always get the list as a return from aggregation query.